# How to implement CSRF protection in WP_List_Table sorting

Tags: wordpress, csrf

I have developed a custom plugin for WordPress, and I am using WP_List_Table for listing data from database.
By default we can allow sorting for columns using this class methods. WordPress will use GET method for that. But it is being vulnerable to CSRF attacks. How can we prevent that? Can we use wp_nonce here?
My url will be something like below when I sort for a field named 'name'

```
admin.php?page=custom-logs&orderby=name&order=asc
```